# Vertx & ADFS Authentication

Tags: java, adfs

Estoy comenzando con Vertx, quisiera implementar lo que es la autenticación mediante SAML, hasta el momento no he encontrado algo que pueda ayudarme para realizar eso.
Alguno tiene guía de como implementarlo

Gracias

Comment: Tu pregunta es un "¿como hago esto?" para recibir ayudar has un trabajo de investigacion o comparte algun avance que tengas, por otra parte lee la documentacion de las tecnologias que estas usando, seguramente ahi conseguiras la repuesta

Comment: Así es, estuve buscando esa documentación que incluya ADFS con vertx pero no encuentro mas que este enlace: https://github.com/pac4j/vertx-pac4j

Comment: Edita tu pregunta y cambia el título por uno que más especifico como "¿Cómo implementar una autenticación mediante SAML?" y lo añade cosas de la documentación que conseguiste, tal vez asi puedas conseguir más ayuda.